# IIS reverse proxy stuck on one file

Tags: docker, iis, reverse-proxy, keycloak, iis-10

I'm setting up IIS (10.0) as a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy is *mostly* working, but it's getting stuck on one file in particular:

[image]

This file (`ace.js`) never leaves the "pending" state.  This happens every time I refresh the page in any browser.

When I navigate to the same page *without* going through my proxy, this file loads without any problems:

[image]

What could be causing this?

The complete URL for this file is http://172.19.243.9/auth/resources/4.3.0.final/admin/keycloak/lib/ui-ace/min/ace.js.

Here's how I'm implementing my reverse proxy in `wwwroot/web.config`:

```
<rule name="RedirectToGoogle" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^auth(\/?.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://keycloak:8080/auth{R:1}" />
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" value="{REMOTE_ADDR}" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
        <set name="HTTP_REFERER" value="" />
    </serverVariables>
</rule>
```

If it's relevant, IIS is running in a Docker network, and the service being proxied (`keycloak`) is in another container on the same network.

---

**Update:** I dug into IIS and the proxied server's logs.  The proxied server's (Keycloak) access logs shows that this file was served with a HTTP 200 with no issues.  However, IIS shows this information on the request:

```
2018-09-13 13:01:12 172.19.242.115 GET /auth/resources/4.3.0.final/admin/keycloak/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js.map X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=e5ac0907-7e2f-4791-8361-f6dcbe76fa0d&SERVER-STATUS=200 80 - 172.19.240.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 121 20030
```

The relevant part is at the very end - `200 0 121 20030`.  From some Googling, the `121` code indicates that "The semaphore timeout period has expired".  I have yet to find a solution to this problem, though.

Comment: What exactly was the HTTP request body sent via reverse proxy? You should show that as part of the question.

Comment: As a note to anyone else who runs into this issue: I experienced this issue when using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 (using Windows containers), but once I deployed the same image to Windows Server 2016 running Docker EE, this issue went away.